# WSO2 APIM can't connect to WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0, ad I configurated a Key Manager of type WSO2 Identity Server.
When I go to my application, to generate the token, I have the following exception:
https://pastebin.com/rjfxLiAA

```
Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient. org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Key Manager IS not configured
```

The IS is not beeing contacted, I have the same error stopping it, so it's only an apim error.
With the same APIM versione I can contact keycloak for example.
I'm running in server mode, openjdk 11

Comment: What is the IS version?

Comment: the latest, 6.0.0 but the error occurs ALSO WITH IS DOWN, so I think that the exception is before the call to IS

Answer (score 0):

With API Manager 4.1.0, it is recommended to use WSO2 IS 5.11.0 - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/reference/product-compatibility/#tested-wso2-products

Comment: I know it ad I'll try, but the error happens also with the IS stopped, furthermore there is no error on IS logs...

Answer (score 0):

Now I used the correct IS version, and I Have this exception:
https://pastebin.com/uRLDJPqx

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/devportal] [2022-11-17 14:05:46,592] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager} - Can not create OAuth application  : admin_151a9ace-ce5d-4d7b-9455-d82f909dbce4_PRODUCTION for application: 222 and key type: PRODUCTION org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KeyManagerClientException: Received status code: 403 Reason:
```